# Jquery wrap function inside div

Tags: jquery

How do I wrap a function inside a div that doesn't exist?

So far, I've tried .append before and after, but that closes the tag. Also tried .html, and wrap right after the function, no luck.

```
$("#testing .input").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).find("li .value").text();
    // start wrap
    $("span.rune > span", this).each(function() {
        var e = $(this).text();
        $("#test-output").append('<span class="' +e+ ' Rune"></span>');
    });
    // stop wrap
    $("#test-output").append('<span>' +txtToNumber[s]+ '</span>');
});
```

Starting HTML :

```
<div id="test-output"></div>
```

Ending HTML :

```
<div id="test-output">
    <div class="three">
        <span class="Z Rune"></span>
        <span class="Y Rune"></span>
        <span class="X Rune"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't exist in the html, I want it created by jquery

Comment: Maybe a more complete example would help.. but if you've created it like this `var $div = $('<div>')`, you can use the variable `$div` to reference the jQuery object as in: `$div.find('selector')`.

Comment: Post some simple HTML (that you *start* with) and show the HTML as you want it *become*. Reading this question as it is I have no idea what it is that you want to do, except that it involves wrapping some unspecified content with an unspecified element.

Comment: I've updated my example, sorry

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping a function into an element? It would be very helpful if you posted "before" HTML and "after" HTML, so as to understand the JavaScript you want. The current code (without any corresponding HTML) is not very meaningful.

Comment: Added HTML, so far my spans are input just fine with the corresponding classes as I want them (then styled with css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create elements in jQuery without appending them. Then they basically "don't exist yet", at least not in the DOM (they are disconnected). What you can also do is creating the `.three` element, append it to the DOM, and then append the `.Rune` elements to it:

```
// create .three element and append it to the DOM
var $three = $("<div>").addClass("three").appendTo("#test-output");

// map these elements to .Rune elements
$("span.rune > span", this).map(function() {
    var e = $(this).text();

    return $("<span>")
             .addClass(e)
             .addClass("Rune")
             .get(0);
}).appendTo($three);  // and append them to .three
```

Comment: may I ask, what does .get(0) do?

Comment: @user1732521: `$("...")` returns a jQuery set, and `.get(0)` returns the first element. Without `.get(0)`, each item in the mapped jQuery set would be a jQuery set itself.

Comment: Thank you! my JSFiddle results http://jsfiddle.net/veksen/ERurF/4/ :)
I have some reading on `.map` to do now!